# Write a google app script to store a PDF from URL in a specific folder in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script

So here is what I want to do:
I have a URL of a PDF document. I want to store it directly into my google drive without downloading it to my hard drive first and then uploading to google drive. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using urlFetch and DocsList, this is pretty straightforward and takes only 3 lines of code :

```
var urlOfThePdf = 'http://www.fostexinternational.com/docs/tech_support/pdfs/280_owners_manual.pdf';// an example of online pdf file
var folderName = 'GAS';// an example of folder name

function saveInDriveFolder(){
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(folderName);// get the folde
  var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlOfThePdf); // get the file content as blob 
  folder.createFile(file);//create the file directly in the folder
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How do you make it a small web app with a minimal GUI so that I can type in the URL and folder name?